# Curve Modifier - not smooth enough deformation

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a plane and added a curve modifier to it. But no matter the number of sub-divisions or loop cuts, the deformation doesn't get smoother beyond a point. I have tried using smooth shading, applying subdivision surface modifier (to the plane as well as to the curve) with sufficient number of sub-divisions, to no avail. Any idea what must be going wrong?
[image: sharp edges protruding regardless of the no. of cuts]

Comment: Increase Resolution in curve's settings. Also place Subdivision Surface with Catmull-Clark option after Curve modifier

Comment: Attach the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4045" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4045/) link to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try both method

**Method 1**

Select the curve go to curve tab and in Resolution - Preview U : increase from 12

[image]

**Method 2**

You have added loop cut vertically and no loop cut horizontally

So just select all and delete with limited dissolve

Press W key and add subdivide and Press f6 to increase the count to above 7

No need of subsurf modifier

Apply smooth shading.

[image]

Comment: Worked, thank you! That was very detailed and lightning quick :)